# flutter how to convert list string to list

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to change a list string to list, there is the string:

```
var liststr = "[['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'], ['one\'s next', 'two\'s next', 'three\'s next', 'four\'s next']]";
```

I tried json.decode, but report error because single quotes, I don't know other ways to solve this problem.

so I want to ask how to solve it in dart, thank you~

Answer (score 1):

Check Out following way to convert string list into list of string.

1) This joints all the elements in one list.

```
var list =
    "[['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'], ['one\'s next', 'two\'s next', 'three\'s next', 'four\'s next']]";
final regExp =
    new RegExp(r"(\w+\\?\'?\w*\s?\w+)"); 
var result = regExp
    .allMatches(list)
    .map((m) => m.group(1))
    .map((String item) => item.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'[\[\],]'), ''))
    .map((m) => m)
    .toList();
print(result);
```

Output:
[one, two, three, four, one, s, next, two, s, next, three, s, next, four, s, next]

2) If You want it list item wise then follow below code.

```
   var list =
        "[['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'], ['one\'s next', 'two\'s next', 'three\'s next', 'four\'s next']]";
    final regExp = new RegExp(r'(?:\[)?(\[[^\]]*?\](?:,?))(?:\])?');
    final regExp2 = new RegExp(r"(\w+\\?\'?\w*\s?\w+)");
    final result = regExp
        .allMatches(list)
        .map((m) => m.group(1))
        .map((String item) => item.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'[\[\],]'), ''))
        .map((m) => [m])
        .toList();
    final result2 = List();
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      result2.add(regExp2
          .allMatches(result[i].toString())
          .map((m) => m.group(1))
          .map((m) => m)
          .toList());
    }

    print(result2[0]);
    print(result2[0][0]);
```

output: [one, two, three, four]

one

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'm sorry I write my code error, liststr is a string, not list.

Comment: I edit my question. tht liststr is var liststr = "[['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'], ['one\'s next', 'two\'s next', 'three\'s next', 'four\'s next']]";

Comment: i update my answer. i hope this will work for you. @hysunny

Comment: Thank you a lot, It's useful for me！

Comment: @hysunny accept the answer if you found it useful so others can also get benefit. Your Welcome.